# Regex exp to change every letter after the literal dot [.] to lower case

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, expression, node-modules

Could anyone help out with regex expression I can run in node to change that changes only the letter that appears immediately after the dot(.) to lower-case? I am reading  And writing back the changed text back to the same text file.

#### Input:

```
$.Carpool[0].NoofSeats], [$.Carpool[1].NoofSeats]
```

So after replace with regex the updated text file should be:

#### Desired Output:

```
[$.carpool[0].noOfSeats], [$.carpool[1].noOfSeats]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dot followed by an uppercase letter can be matched with `\.[A-Z]`.

To convert it to lowercase, you can do

```
str = str.replace(/\.[A-Z]/g, (m0) => m0.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Great solution! Just a little improvement you can replace (m0) => m0.toLowerCase() for m0 => m0.toLowerCase() to make it even easier to read.

Comment: ok @melpomene at the end that is just a question of styles and styles are subjectives.

Comment: @melpomene Reposting the question- I have two folders, input and output folder with many text files in the above format. How do I read all the files from the input folder run the regex and write all the updated files to another output folder?I am using nodejs. I got to reading all files from the dir.

Answer (score -1):

These expressions would simply work here:

```
\.([A-Za-z])
\.([A-Z])
```

being replaced by `\.\L$1`, which `\L` or `\U` may not be supported/available in JavaScript, instead of which, we would simply apply `.toLowerCase();` function.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lm8Y1T/1/)

Comment: melpomene and Emma both of your solutions worked. Thank you.

Comment: Now I have two folders, input and output folder with many text files in the above format. How do I read all the files from the input folder run the regex and write all the updated files to the output folder. I am using nodejs.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the post Emma. That post has it for reading only one file from a directory. I would want to read all the files in the folder and give the output for all the files in the output directory.